# get Activity Owner's Role from the Org Hierarchy

Tags: formula, role-hierarchy

Is there a way to get the Activity Owner's role in the hierarchy as part of a formula?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `Owner:User.UserRole.Name` ?

Comment: I just tested... and confirmed that actually is valid.